# Getting the angular app to run when using protractor

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I must be missing something here ...

I'm trying to use protractor to run e2e tests for my angular application. The configuration file is something along the lines of:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

specs: [          
    'src/**/*.e2e.js'
],

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'
},

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/app/',

framework: 'jasmine',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose : true,
    includeStackTrace : true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
}
```

The test looks something like this:

```
describe('example test', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('index.html');
    });

    it('should test something trivial', function() {
        expect(2).toEqual(2);
    });
});
```

I'm using grunt to run it, with "grunt-protractor-runner".
When grunt gets to the protractor task, I see the following (running grunt with --verbose):

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://172.17.113.30:53524/wd/hub
```

Then the firefox browser window opens, and resolves the URL correctly to: `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`

However (and here's the question finally ...), firefox cannot find the page, i.e. I get the following error:

[image: firefox error message screen shot]

I tried running it with Chrome as well, but I get the same result.

My question is, what am I missing ? 
In other words, who's job it is to get the angular app deployed at localhost:8000 ?
Is the deployment done by protractor/selenium/grunt, or do I need to deploy it on some webserver myself ?

Given that I can't find any question like mine online, I guess I'm missing something trivial here. Please help.

Comment: Are you able to see content when you open this URL manually?

Comment: No, when should I see content there, during the running of the test only, or all the time ?

Comment: Protractor's job is to run the tests(which it is doing correctly). Whatever URL you need to test(for example google.com and in your case http://localhost:8000/app/index.html) should be up and running before you start your tests

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, I need to setup another task (possibly a grunt task) that will deploy my angular app to some web server ? I tried simply running the tests on the local file (why would I need more than that actually ?), but it cries out that the scripts do not have access to the local file system.

Comment: Yes . Firstly your angular app needs to be deployed(not necessarily a web-server, a localhost would work equally well). Tests will run on a deployed app(can be deployed on local machine) not on just an undeployed local file. Once it is deployed, your current tests would work just perfectly fine!

Comment: What do you mean by deployed on a localhost and not on a web server ? How does that work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67971/discussion-between-sakshi-singla-and-eitanfar).

Comment: I am not sure how an angular app is deployed, but it is something similar to Tomcat server for JSP applications!

Comment: I'm in the chat room you created by the way, let's continue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as discussed. Angular App needs to be deployed before executing any tests. Deploy the Angular app first and then start Testing using Protractor.