# AngularJS protractor tests give 'This site can’t be reached'

Tags: angularjs, protractor

So this error just started happening and I'm not really sure what changed or where to look to fix it.

But when I run my e2e tests chrome pops up does it's `data:text/html,<html></html>` thing then goes to where `browser.get()` specifies but doesn't load anything.

It just keeps giving a 'This site can't be reached' message.

my protractor.conf.js file

```
exports.config = {

  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

  specs: [
    '*.js'
  ],
  rootElement: 'html',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }

};
```

my scenarios.js

```
'use strict';

/* https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/toc.md */

describe('my app', function() {

  describe('record', function() {


    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('#/record');

    });

    it('should be true', function () {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

and part of my scripts from package.json

```
...
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    "protractor-quick": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
...
```

Comment: I'm sure you have tried, but did you try browsing to loalhost:8000 in a separate window to be sure the site is up?

Comment: I have but it doesn't show there either. It's almost like it's not being started up. I've tried added `--verbose` to the end of my protractor command but the only thing that prints out is ` E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:8000/#/record: retries looking for angular exceeded`

Comment: So how is the application being started up normally? E.g a gulp task??

Comment: In my package.json scripts I have `"start"; "http-server ./app -a localhost -p 8000` so to start I just run `npm start`

Comment: @mindparse but it seems to work fine if, in another prompt, I start the app first and then run the tests. Is that how it should be?

Comment: correct, see my answer

Comment: Ok thanks! That's really weird because for a while I was able to run the tests without starting up seperately. But I never tried to go to the site manually, maybe I had it ghost running the background somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor is not responsible for building and launching the target application you wish to run your tests against.

When running against localhost, typically you will have a task (grunt\gulp\webpack) you kick off in a separate prompt and then run the protractor command separately.

See - [Getting the angular app to run when using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718703/getting-the-angular-app-to-run-when-using-protractor)